# Java: How can I use a single scanner input for multiple calculations?

Tags: java, variables

Say one milk carton is 3.78 liters and one liter cost $0.38.  I ask the user for the amount of milk they have and put that in a double variable.  Now I want to use that variable to calculate how much cartons I will need to hold the milk, which is the variable / 3.78.  Now, how do I use that user input variable again with that same value they entered to perform another calculation such as, displaying the cost of milk according to the amount of liters after displaying the cartons needed.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: try this doc [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

double price_per_liter = 0.38;

System.out.print("Enter amount of milk to buy: "); 
double milk_amount = scanner.nextdDouble(); //ask for user input

double cartonsNeeded = milk_amount / price_per_liter ;

double total  =  milk_amount * price_per_liter ; // reused the milk_amount variable

System.out.println("Total amount: "+ total
                   + "Cartons needed: "+ cartonsNeeded);
```

Comment: Thank you good sir!  Works like a charm.  I needed to add a couple of variables.

Comment: good for you @Marcus. please mark my answer if it helps for others to easily find the answer..

Comment: How do I mark it?  This was my first post.  I can't vote it up till I have more pts.

Comment: @Marcus.. Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows. :)

Answer (score -1):

Store the input in a variable and use it later. E.g.

```
double input;
input = scanner.nextdDouble();
result = input/3.78;
output = input * .38;
```